# How do I change the indentation on LiClipse's JavaScript formatter?

Tags: eclipse, liclipse

I'm using LiClipse 1.4.0 and would like to configure the JavaScript auto-formatter (`CTRL-SHIFT-F`). Even though the editor tab spacing is 2, the formatter's spacing is 4. I've tried editing the YAML JavaScript config file inside the LiClipse application folder on OSX, and I've tried putting `.settings/.javascript.liclipseprefs` in the project per http://www.liclipse.com/customize_javascript.html, but neither seems to have an effect.

How can LiClipse's JavaScript editor be successfully configured?

Answer (score 1):

Latest LiClipse versions have a proper way to configure the Javascript code-formatter.

As a reference, see: http://www.liclipse.com/customize_javascript.html

---

Older LiClipse versions:

There's a hack you can do for now which is changing the default value in beautify.js... to do that, open the jar: LiClipse\plugins\com.brainwy.liclipse.editor.javascript_XXX.jar (with some .zip utility), extract the file com/beautify.js, look for the line:

opt.indent_size = options.indent_size ? parseInt(options.indent_size, 10) : 4;

and change 4 to the indent_size you want and the override the previous beautify.js from the .zip (note that you may have to do that with LiClipse closed).

I've created issue: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/LiClipse/138 to provide a better way to do it in the future.